# Problems while using handlers in android service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-handler, linegraph

I am new to android and trying to understand android services. I am working on a tutorial on updating `Temperature` readings on a `Line Graph`.

The following is the my code for service

```
    public class Temperature extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";
    private static final int PROCESS_SENSOR_DATA_ON_UI = 801;
    private boolean isRunning  = false;
    public static ArrayList<Float> tempValueC=new ArrayList<Float>();
    private Handler mUiHandler2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mUiHandler2 = new Handler(new UiHandlerCallback2());}
            class UiHandlerCallback2 implements Handler.Callback {

                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.what) {
                        case COMPLETE_INIT:

                            break;
                        case PROCESS_EVENT_DEVICE_UNSUPPORTED:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_unsupported_device,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case PROCESS_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE_UI:
                            //updateConnectionStateWidgets();
                            break;
                        case PROCESS_BATTERY_STATUS_UI:
                            //   updateBatteryLevelWidget(msg.arg1);
                            break;

                        case PROCESS_SENSOR_DATA_ON_UI:
                            processSensorData((byte[]) msg.obj);
                             break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
             private void processSensorData(byte[] sensorData) {
             //code for temperature update
            }
         }
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }
```

I get an error which is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

`UiHandlerCallback2` to check for any messages.

I get the error at the creation of the handler  `mUiHandler2 = new Handler(new UiHandlerCallback2());`

I want to know where am I going wrong. I am still starting with the basics so any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Otto. It's a lib for sending data between app components easily.

http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Thanks for the information. But, I want to use android service for the implementation.  Any ideas?